# Line drawn using CGContextSetLineWidth becomes thinner

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am drawing a multilevelPieChart, currently i am filling 2 colours to one of my slice (The slice will be seen with the picture of the 2 added colours). But the lines of the slice for  which the colours have been filled looks much thinner, than the other slice with no colours.  What do i need to do to maintain the same width. Currently i am using CGContextSetLineWidth, to draw my lines.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the help section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question as-is cannot be answered since we don't know _how_ you are drawing. Please **edit your question** and add your code. **Do not post your code in a comment!** Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the update..Will post the code shortly!